# Is there a free vnc server on Linux? or a way to create a shared desktop for free

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I want to access to my Ubuntu computer by graphical interface, gnome-remote-desktop doesn't do the job for me because I want a smaller screen than the original one.

I already installed tight-vnc, but it's not great, or at least I do not succeed in setting my keyboard correctly.

Is there a good free vnc server? Can Xorg be configured to use vnc? I don't find anything about that on the internet?

Thanks

Comment: "good free vnc server" that is asking for opinions. We don't accept those. All VNC In the repo's are good and probably all free.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? version 22.04 and above has **Gnome Remote Desktop** builtin. You just need to turn it on in the settings.

Comment: @user68186, thanks for your advise. So, **Remote Desktop** are controlled by **Sharing** sub-menu in Ubuntu Settings, as "Screen Sharing" and "Media Sharing" ?

Comment: @TomNewton I have two options under "Sharing": 1. Remote Desktop, and 2. Media Sharing. The Remote Desktop sets up the **Gnome Remote Desktop**. The **Media Sharing** option. uses `rygel`, I think. It starts an DLNA server.

Comment: @user68186, much thanks for clarification!

Comment: Try installing tigervnc